# Diagonalization of quadratic form on a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Lets say you have a subspace of a vectorspace which is defined such that $S=\{x: x^Tg_i=0, i=1,\ldots n\}$, basically the orthogonal compement to the space spanned of the g-vectors.

Assume also that you have a symmetric matrix $H$, and that for every vector in S, $x^THx <0$. Now H resembles something that is negative definite, but since we only have it for the vectors in S, we may not have a negative definite matrix.

But since H is symmetric we have that $H=PDP^T$, where P is an orthogonal matrix. We know that for any vector z, if we change the basis to the vectors in P, $z=Pz'$, then $z^THz=(P
^Tz')^THP^Tz'=z'^TDz=z'^{2}_1\lambda_1+\ldots+z'^{2}_n\lambda_n$.

But lets say that we look at an x in S and use the change of basis $x=Px'$, we then get:

$x'^{2}_1\lambda_1+\ldots+x'^{2}_n\lambda_n$ We know that this quantity is always negative for x non-zero(and x in S), but that H is not nececarrily negative-definite, so we don't know that all eigenvalues are negative.

**Is there a way to write $x^THx$ as $x'^{2}_1\lambda_1+\ldots+x'^{2}_n\lambda_n$ with all negative eigenvalues, or how is this situation best described?**

**The reason I am asking is that I need a lower bound on $|x^THx|$, given $|x|$, and if we were not in the subspace the negative-definite property would have given me this by looking at the eigenvalue with smallest absolute-value, but is there a way to solve this in our situation?**

Comment: If you mean a weighted sum of $n$ squares, this is not always possible. E.g. suppose the underlying space is $\mathbb R^3$, $H=I_3$ and $n=1$ with $g_1=(1,0,0)^T$. Then $S$ is 2-dimensional and for a generic $x\in S$, the quantity $x^THx$ is a weighted sum of 2 squares. In general, if $S$ is $k$-dimensional, you should be able to write $x^THx$ as a weighted (by eigenvalues of some matrix) sum of $k$ squares.

Comment: @user1551 thanks, what I really need is to find a lower bound on $|x^THx|$, and in the general case they find this bound by writing out the weighted sum with the eigenvalues. So I am wondering about two things, if we can do something similar here, or if not, how do we find the bound.

Comment: This sort of things can be obtained by performing a singular value decomposition $G=U\Sigma V^T$ (here the columns of $G$ are your $g$-vectors) and by orthogonal diagonalization of the trailing $k\times k$ submatrix of $U^THU$.

Answer (score 0):

The ambient vector space is actually irrelevant. You shouldn't think of it at all. You have a vector space $S$ and a negative definite bilinear form $K:=H|_S$. You can use everything you know about this setting.

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't really heard about the theory of billinear forms. I looked it up on Wikipedia, but I don't really see how I am supposed to solve this.

Comment: @user119615 What I'm saying is that the last paragraph in your post has all the answers. You write "if we were not in the subspace...". The thing is that, as written in my answer, you shouldn't think of $S$ as a subspace. Think of $S$ as the vector space.

Comment: When I only look at S I still get that $x^THx$ = $x'^{2}_1\lambda_1+\ldots+x'^{2}_n\lambda_n$, but now all the $\lambda$'s may not be negative, so I don't see how to find the bound. Since in our case some eigenvalues may be positive and some negative, I can't just pick the one with the smallest absolute-value?(and one may even be zero)

Comment: @user119615 All the $\lambda$'s are negative. Forget about $H$ as you know it. Pick a basis of $S$, and let $K$ be the (smaller) matrix representing $H$ with respect to this basis. Then $K$ is negative definite. Proceed from here as if $S$ is the original vector space.